# Is it possible to use a TI-89 calculator to calculate the stationary measure of a markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, matrix-equations, calculator

The Stationary measure also known as the Invariant Distribution of a markov chain, M, is a row vector of values that when multiplied by the probability transition matrix, P, of that MC returns the same vector back as the product, M*P=M.

I can solve this by hand using a system of equations that involves doing the vector-matrix multiplication of the PTM and a vector a variables, setting that equal to the same vector of variables and using the fact that the variables must add up to 1 as the last equation in the system. But this is time consuming and prone to errors so it would be great if I could calculate this in the TI-89 calculator.

Ex: 
M = [m1, m2, m3]

M*P_i1 = m1

M*P_i2 = m2

m1 + m2 + m3 = 1

Comment: Solving $xP=x$ for $x$ is the same as solving $xP-x=0$ i.e. $x(P-I)=0$.  This is the same as solving for the left-kernel/left-nullspace of $P-I$, i.e. solving for the kernel/nullspace of $(P-I)^T$.  If I remember correctly, there is a nullspace calculator on the 89.  You will need to complete the process yourself by normalizing a vector in the nullspace manually, but that should be trivial to do.

Comment: This reminds me of the "how do you find the height of a tower using a barometer" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question. No doubt as many ways to use a Ti-89 to calculate the stationary measure as there are ways to use a barometer to find building height.